# tinymce + localstorage

Tags: tinymce, local-storage

I have an issue at my work. The website is administered by a company and they do not want to activate the plug-in autosave on TinyMCE. So, to avoid people from losing their texts from tinyMCE, we decided to use localStorage to save the work. We can write javascripts on the website. Is there anyway localStorage save the text inside the tinyMCE?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

To set a variable containing the editor contents use:

```
localStorage.setItem('your_editor_content', tinymce.get('your_editor_id').getContent() );
```

You may use a timeout or other tinymce events to store the contents to the localStorage this way.

To set the editor content of the content in the localStorage on editor init use

```
function myCustomOnInit() {
        var content =  localStorage.getItem('your_editor_content');
        tinymce.get('your_editor_id').setContent(content)
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        oninit : myCustomOnInit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the below code in tinymce.init

setup : function(ed) {

```
      ed.onChange.add(function() {
            localStorage.setItem(key, tinymce.get('id').getContent());
      });
```

}

if any value is changed in the RTE, it will be stored in the local storage, then u can get the same value with the key.